# The asymptotics of the following expression

Tags: summation, asymptotics

I wonder the asymptotics of the expression $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n!}{kn^k(n-k)!}$$ when $n$ tends to be infinity and don't know how to do it. I have tried Stirling approximation but I think it doens't work. I can figure out that it's in $ O(\log n)$ scale but can't figure out its relation with $ \Theta(\log n / \log\log n)$. Can anybody give a guide on how to get its asymptotics? I conjecture that it doesn't exceed $ \Theta(\log n / \log\log n)$. Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: The sum $S$ is equal to
$$-\frac {(n - 1)!} {n^{n - 1}} [z^n] f(z),
\quad f(z) = e^{n z} \ln(1 - z).$$
Cauchy's integral formula and the steepest descent method give
$$[z^n] f(z) \sim
\frac 1 {2 \pi i} \int_{1 - i \epsilon}^{1 + i \epsilon}
 \frac {f(z)} {z^{n + 1}} dz \sim
\frac 1 {2 \pi} \int_{\mathbb R}  \ln(-i \xi) e^{n (1 - \xi^2/2)} d\xi, \\
S \sim \frac {\ln n} 2.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewriting your sum as :
\begin{align}
\tag{1}S(n)&:=\frac {n!}{n^n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n^{n-k}}{k\,(n-k)!}\\
&=\frac {n!}{n^n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{n^{i}}{(n-i)\,i!}\\
&=\frac {n!}{n^n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{i^{i}}{(n-i)\,i!}\left(\frac {n}{i}\right)^i\\
&\approx\sqrt{2\pi\,n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{e^{\,i-n}}{(n-i)\,\sqrt{2\pi i}}\left(\frac {n}{i}\right)^i\\
\tag{2}&\approx\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{e^{\,i-n}}{(n-i)}\left(\frac {n}{i}\right)^{i+1/2}\,=:A(n)\\
\end{align}
Stirling's approximation with the error term $\displaystyle\;  n!\approx\sqrt{2 \pi\,n}\, \left(\frac{n}{e} \right)^n \left( 1 + O \left( \frac{1}{n} \right) \right)$ was used.
Observe that the last term of $A(n)$ is nearly $\dfrac 11$, the previous nearly $\dfrac 12$ and then $\dfrac 13$ and so on so that we obtain 'nearly' a sum of terms $\dfrac 1k$ with an error coefficient of order $\left(1+ O \left( \frac{1}{n-k} \right)\right)\left(1+ O \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)\right)$.
This allows to obtain $\;S(n)-A(n)=O \left( \frac{\log n}{n} \right)$ and thus to study $A(n)$ instead of $S(n)$.

We can't conclude that $\,A(n)\sim H(n)\,$ because the values of the sum is decreasing much faster than $\dfrac 1k$ after "a while". More exactly for $\,k:=n-i\,$ and $\,n\gg 1\,$ the first $k$ terms become :
\begin{align}
b_k&:= \frac{e^{\,-k}}{k}\left(\frac {n}{n-k}\right)^{n-k+1/2}\\
&= \frac{e^{\,-k}}{k}\left(1-\frac kn\right)^{\large{-n\left(1-\frac{k-1/2}n\right)}},\quad\text{expanding }\;\left(1-\frac kn\right)^{-n}\;\text{to second order :}\\
&\approx  \frac{e^{\,-k}}{k}e^{\large{\left(k+\frac{k^2}{2n}\right)\left(1-\frac{k-1/2}n\right)}},\quad\text{neglecting the $\frac 1{n^2}$ terms after simplification :}\\
&\approx  \frac{e^{\large-{\frac{k\,(k-1)}{2\,n}}}}{k}\\
\end{align}

Notice that the exponential will become smaller than $\dfrac 12$ for $\,k\,$ somewhere between $\,\left[\sqrt{n}\right]\,$ and $\,\left[\sqrt{2\,n}\right]\,$ so that  the main term of the asymptotic should rather be $\,\dfrac {\log(n)}2\,$ than $\,\log(n)$.
With some black magic used to get the additional corrective term we will write our new approximation as a series (since $b_k$ is very small for $\,k\ge n\gg 1$) :
$$\tag{3}B(n):=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  \frac{e^{\large-{\frac{k\,(k-1)}{2\,n}}}}{k}-\frac 16\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2\,n}}$$

The interest of the approximations $(2)$ and $(3)$ is that numerical evaluation is much faster with these two sums (as you may see in the table at the end). Further $(3)$ allows to get the asymptotic term with any precision (I got $\dfrac{\gamma+\log(2)}2$) and thus my "final conjecture" with $\gamma$ the Euler–Mascheroni constant :
$$\tag{4} S(n)= \frac{\log(2\,n)+\gamma}2+O\left(\frac 1{\sqrt{n}}\right)$$

Table of values for $\ \displaystyle S(n)-\frac 12 \log(n)\ $ and the corresponding approximations $(2)$ and $(3)$ :
\begin{array} {c|c|c|c}
n&\text{Exact}\;S(n)-\log(n)/2&A(n)-\log(n)/2&B(n)-\log(n)/2\\
\hline
1000& 0.648336893251805&  0.648340255305227& 0.648310001946645\\
10000& 0.639353578731186& 0.639353683741043& 0.639350829257599\\
100000&  0.636501976201853 &  0.636501979510217& 0.636501699321884\\
1000000&-&  0.635599138656474& 0.635599110802617\\
10000000&-& 0.635313528088334& 0.635313525308151\\
100000000&-&  0.635223199313196& 0.635223199035342\\
1000000000&-&  0.635194633766179& 0.635194633738398\\
\infty&-&-& 0.635181422730739\\
\end{array}

(the limits as $\,n\to \infty\,$ should all be equal!)

Comment: Hi Raymond ! Long time no speak. How are you doing in this terrible time ? By the way, one more nice and elegant solution !

Comment: @Claude: Fine thank you (working at home for a year now!). Glad you liked my solution (I began working at it and couldn't stop without the asymptotic!). I hope you are well too (as it seems from your neat progression curve!) All the best,

Comment: More precisely $$S(n)= \frac{\log(2\,n)+\gamma}2+\sqrt{\frac {\pi}{2\,n}}\left(\frac 13-\frac 1{540\,n}-\frac{25}{6048\,n^2}\right)-\frac 1{18\,n}+\frac 7{810\,n^2}+\frac{176}{127575\,n^3}+o\left(\frac 1{n^3}\right)$$

Comment: More and more impressive !

Comment: Thanks for the kind words @Claude. This is a numerical result using pari (not that I think it wrong). Do you know if Mathematica could provide such an expansion for a finite sum of $n$ terms possibly with some help like subracting $\frac {\log(n)}2$ and asking for an expansion in powers of $\sqrt{\frac 1n}$ ?

Comment: Be sure I tried a few things after your first answer ! Absolutely  nothing came ... except that my computer froze ! Cheers and *bravo* again ! Cheers :-)

Comment: I feel a little guilty for your froze and time spent sorry. I got Mma 12 last year and declared a function S[n_] for the sum and Series[S[n],{n,Infinity,5}] returned something related (but not easy to interpret to be honest with DifferenceRoot bla bla). Thanks for your time anyway. Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

Let us denote your sum by $S(n)$. Making Maxim's calculations in the comments more precise, we can confirm Raymond Manzoni's asymptotics (with a more precise error term). Simple manipulation of Maxim's integral gives
$$
S(n) \sim \frac{{n!}}{{n^n e^{ - n} \sqrt {2\pi n} }}\frac{1}{2}\sqrt {\frac{n}{\pi }} \left( {\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - nt} t^{ - 1/2} ( - \log t)dt}  - \log 2\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - nt} t^{ - 1/2} dt} } \right)
$$
up to an absolute error which is $\mathcal{O}(n^{-1})$ times the leading order. By Theorem 2 on page 70 of R. Wong's book *Asymptotic Approximations of Integrals*, we have
$$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - nt} t^{ - 1/2} ( - \log t)dt}  = \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{n}} \log n\left( {1 + \frac{{2\log 2 + \gamma }}{{\log n}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\log ^2 n}}} \right)} \right).
$$
Also
$$
 - \log 2\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - nt} t^{ - 1/2} dt}  =  - \log 2\sqrt {\frac{\pi }{n}} 
$$
and, by Stirling's formula,
$$
\frac{{n!}}{{n^n e^{ - n} \sqrt {2\pi n} }} = 1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right).
$$
Collecting all the results, we finally obtain
$$
S(n) = \frac{1}{2}\log n + \frac{{\log 2 + \gamma }}{2} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\log n}}} \right).
$$
Taking more terms in the asymptotic expansion coming from R. Wong's theorem, we can replace the error term by an asymptotic expansion in inverse powers of $\log n$.

Comment: Neat and short expansion by Maxim and you. Concerning the error term I merely observed that the error term appeared numerically to be something like $\;\dfrac {0.418}{\sqrt{n}}$ for $n<30000$ but stopped there. Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Your $k$-th term is equal to

$$\frac1k\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} (1-\frac{i}{n}).$$

The product is strictly smaller than one, so the sum is dominated by $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k = H_n \sim \log n,$ bearing out your $O(\log n)$ statement.

If $k > n/\log n,$ then the product is of order $o(1/k),$ so is negligeable, and for smaller $k$ it can be estimated by taking logs and approximating by the integral, so you can get the precise constant (if you use the Euler-Mclaurin formula, you will see that the integral approximation is very good).

Comment: I think that the final conclusion is in $O(logn/loglogn)$ scale and could you please make some tighter estimate of the value?